# Onbarclick not working into barchart EazeGraph

Tags: android, graph

I am following [this](https://github.com/blackfizz/EazeGraph) link for displaying of animated graphs for android.

I have implemented for Stackbar chart, it's showing correctly but when I try to click on bar click event not calling and when user click on little bit left to each bar it's getting click event.

Please check the following code which for calculate bar position & gesture detector.

Anyone knows about this issue ?

```
protected void calculateBarPositions(int _DataSize) {

        int dataSize = mScrollEnabled ? mVisibleBars : _DataSize;
        float barWidth = mBarWidth;
        float margin = mBarMargin;
        if (!mFixedBarWidth) {
            // calculate the bar width if the bars should be dynamically displayed
            barWidth = (mAvailableScreenSize / _DataSize) - margin;
        } else {
            if (_DataSize < mVisibleBars) {
                dataSize = _DataSize;
            }
            // calculate margin between bars if the bars have a fixed width
            float cumulatedBarWidths = barWidth * dataSize;
            float remainingScreenSize = mAvailableScreenSize - cumulatedBarWidths;
            margin = remainingScreenSize / dataSize;
        }

        boolean isVertical = isVerticalAlignment;

        int calculatedSize = (int) ((barWidth * _DataSize) + (margin * _DataSize));
        int contentWidth = isVertical ? mGraphWidth : calculatedSize;
        int contentHeight = isVertical ? calculatedSize : mGraphHeight;
        mContentRect = new Rect(0, 0, contentWidth, contentHeight);
        mCurrentViewport = new RectF(0, 0, mGraphWidth, mGraphHeight);

        calculateBounds(barWidth, margin);
        mLegend.invalidate();
        mGraph.invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * The gesture listener, used for handling simple gestures such as double touches, scrolls,
     * and flings.
     */
    private final GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener mGestureListener
            = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {

            if (mCurrentViewport.left + distanceX > mContentRect.left && mCurrentViewport.right + distanceX < mContentRect.right) {
                mCurrentViewport.left += distanceX;
                mCurrentViewport.right += distanceX;
            }

            if (mCurrentViewport.top + distanceY > mContentRect.top && mCurrentViewport.bottom + distanceY < mContentRect.bottom) {
                mCurrentViewport.top += distanceY;
                mCurrentViewport.bottom += distanceY;
            }

            invalidateGlobal();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            fling((int) -velocityX, (int) -velocityY);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            // The user is interacting with the pie, so we want to turn on acceleration
            // so that the interaction is smooth.
            if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
                stopScrolling();
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    private void fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {

        mScroller.fling(
                (int) mCurrentViewport.left,
                (int) mCurrentViewport.top,
                velocityX,
                velocityY,
                0, mContentRect.width() - mGraphWidth,
                0, mContentRect.height() - mGraphHeight);

        // Start the animator and tell it to animate for the expected duration of the fling.
        mScrollAnimator.setDuration(mScroller.getDuration());
        mScrollAnimator.start();
    }

    private void tickScrollAnimation() {
        if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
            mScroller.computeScrollOffset();
            int currX = mScroller.getCurrX();
            int currY = mScroller.getCurrY();

            if (currX > mContentRect.left && currX + mGraphWidth < mContentRect.right) {
                mCurrentViewport.left = currX;
                mCurrentViewport.right = currX + mGraphWidth;
            }

            if (currY > mContentRect.top && currY + mGraphHeight < mContentRect.bottom) {
                mCurrentViewport.top = currY;
                mCurrentViewport.bottom = currY + mGraphHeight;
            }
        } else {
            mScrollAnimator.cancel();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add relevant pieces of code

Comment: @VadimKotov I have added code please check